# Android Checkbox listview select all (disable/enable)

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want to disable/enable all checkboxes in listview. infact want to get select all behaviour by clicking on top checkbox.

thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me, where I'm using a cursor adapter, not just an `ArrayListAdapter` for my list items:

```
final ListView list = getListView();
for ( int i=0; i< getListAdapter().getCount(); i++ ) {
        list.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

`list.getChildCount` doesn't work because it only seems to count what's been drawn immediately (not everything that's off the screen) so `childCount` might only be 6 or 8 items when the entire list is 100 or more items.  Also as I had to use `list.setItemChecked` to get the items to 'stay checked' -- at least in my case where my list items were instances of `CheckedTextView`.

Comment: How can I work with buttons like this?

Comment: thank you.. i've facing troble because childCount

Answer (score 21):

```
for(int i=0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
    RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(i);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.MyListViewCheckBox);
    cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

You need to edit this code to handle both enabling and disabling, but I hope you get the idea !

Also, this only checks each checkbox, make sure you are returning an id or object from your list in order to send/save the data elsewhere.

Comment: sorted.. thanks so much Abhinav.. much apprecaited

Comment: This code creates some weird behavior when I check all items and then uncheck one item. Solution from Thom Nichols is better.

Comment: I have buttons in my listview. When click a button outside of listview, I need to change the background of the entire buttons present in the listview. I used your code, and got error. How to achieve this.

Comment: This checks only the items which are currently in view. So if you have a listView with more items than the view can show, not all items will be checked. The answer from Thom Nichols is indeed the proper solution.

Comment: working like charm

Answer (score 0):

just add one more parameter in adapter as

```
Boolean Ex.MyAdapter adapter = new Save_Weight_Adapter(this, R.layout.layoutname, array, false);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

on select all button click listener add this code

```
MyAdapter adapter = new Save_Weight_Adapter(this, R.layout.layoutname, array, true);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and check in adpater

```
if(chk) {
    blue_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    blue_check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run this long-running task off the UI thread. When you click button in OnClickListener:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                            final int position = i;
                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    list.setItemChecked(pos, true);  
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

and in onCreate() :

```
this.mHandler = new Handler();
```

Each item in list view should be Checkable like CheckableRelativeLayout that implements Checkable interface.