# where to perform onClickListener and how?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button, android-checkbox

I have an activity which have a button and a listview(with chechbox, image and text).

I am Making the listview from the customAdapter class which extends the `BaseAdapter` class.

I am handling checkboxes in that customAdapter class.

Now my problem is that how to know that which item is checked and how to perform action on

that checked listItems.Because my button is in the activity but i need to perfom that `onClickListener` in that customadapter class
??

Thanks for help.

Comment: So you are trying to record which check box is checked in the list?

Comment: yes i am exactly looking for that. and also where to perfom the button onClickListener and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put the Button click listener inside of your GetView() method, where you inflate the view for each row in your list.

For the checkbox items you would do the same..it would look something like this in your getview()

```
CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.c_checkbox);

    if(cbx.isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Checked position " + position, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: How to perform button onClickListener for all checked items in listview. for example removing all checked item from list on button click.

Comment: Is the button inside of each row in the listview? Or is it just 1 button?

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312069/uncheck-all-checkboxes-in-a-custom-listview

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom-made `OnItemClickListener` that implements `OnClickListener`.

```
private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    public MyAdapter() {
        /* Your constructor */
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
        }

        // take the CheckBox and set the listener.
        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        cbx.setOnClickListener(this);

        // set the listener for the whole row.
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Row button clicked");
    }
}

private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{           
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onItemClick at position" + mPosition);                      
    }               
}
```

}

Also note that putting a focusable view in a list item prevents the firing of onListItemClick() when the list item is clicked.

Hope this helps.