# Block checkBox's in a listView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listviewitem

I have a listView  (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`) where each row of list have a checkbox.

I need to block all checkbox's when click in one button. But I don't know how i can block ALL checkbox's simultaneously.

```
if(checkAll.isChecked()==true){
            all.clear();
            //É adicionado cada id ao array list
            for(int i=0 ; i<listViewSocios.getCount() ; i++){
                listViewSocios.setItemChecked(i, true);

            }
        }
```

All the checkbox's in each row are checked but i want also enabled all this checkbox
Can you help me? thanks

---

I try this way but don't work....

```
 for(int i=0 ; i<listViewSocios.getCount() ; i++){
                listViewSocios.setItemChecked(i, true);
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)listViewSocios.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                cb.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: You want to block or to enable the CheckBox??

Comment: Check [Android Checkbox listview select all (disable/enable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553186/android-checkbox-listview-select-all-disable-enable)

Comment: I want setEnabled(true); for all of the checkbox of listview. But i don't know how i do to all of them..

Answer (score 2):

Disable your checkbox click event by this code

```
theCheckBox.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: But this work's for one checkbox. How can do this for all of checkbox oh listview with multi-choice?

Comment: Perfect! A checkbox was capturing all clicks inside a ListView's item and just by setting `android:clickable=false` in my layout file solved my problem. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem....

```
for(int i=0 ; i<listViewSocios.getCount() ; i++){
    listViewSocios.setItemChecked(i, true);
    CheckedTextView cb = (CheckedTextView)listViewSocios.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    cb.setEnabled(false);
 }
```

I don't remember how pass for each child of listView. But I remembered. XD

Thanks for your time.... :)