# How to select all checkBox by clicking on the top checkbox in recyclerview? only with the help of setonCheckedChangedListener?

Tags: android

To be more specific, I want to know that how can we select all items in a custom list in recycler view(list is made up of only checkbox) by clicking a checkbox which says select all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting All Items in a Listview on checkbox select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690605/selecting-all-items-in-a-listview-on-checkbox-select)

Comment: Well if you inflate a row with a checkbox in it then it will be shown, so you could have a layout with your content and a checkbox and when you click on check all excute a code in your recycler view adapter to display the checkbox view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329079/select-all-checkboxes-in-recyclerview?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

WHen the select all box is clicked, walk through your children's data models and set the selected flag on all of them to true.  Then call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter to redraw the view.

Comment: This is to be done in Adapter class right and in the class where I find the checkbox id ?

Answer (score 0):

create a list with CheckBox in adapter class

```
List<CheckBox> intradayCheckboxsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and add every CheckBox to list in **onBindViewHolder**()

```
intradayCheckboxsList.add(holder.interested_item_checkbox);
```

in onCheckedChanged() method call this method

```
void checkBoxOperation(List<CheckBox> checkBoxList,boolean what){
        for (CheckBox checkBox : checkBoxList ){
            checkBox.setChecked(what);
        }
    }
```

**what true** it will check all

**what false** it will uncheck all