# Select all checkboxes in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

How can I select all checkboxes in `recyclerView?`

I try to do it like this:

**in Adapter:**

```
   public void selectAll(){
        Log.e("onClickSelectAll","yes");
        isSelectedAll=true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PersonDTO item = dataSet.get(position);
        holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
        if (!isSelectedAll) holder.cbSelect.setSelected(false);
        else holder.cbSelect.setSelected(true);}
```

In `layout` `Activity` I have a `button` with `onClickListener`:

```
 private void onClickSelectAll(View view) {

        getSelectPersonsAdapter().selectAll();
    }
```

Comment: And what's the result of doing it like this?

Comment: just change setSelected to setChecked

Comment: @RahulMandaliya It's helped, thanks! Make answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You made a simple mistake here

```
  if (!isSelectedAll) holder.select_item.setChecked(false);
    else holder.select_item.setChecked(true);
```

change `setSelected` into `setChecked` thats it

Answer (score 8):

for both **Select All** and **Unselect All**

activty

```
 checkall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkall.isChecked()){
                categoryAdapter.selectAll();
            }
            else {
                categoryAdapter.unselectall();
            }


        }
    });
```

in adapter

```
  public void selectAll(){
        isSelectedAll=true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void unselectall(){
        isSelectedAll=false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyviewHolder holder, int position) {
        final CategoryListItems list = categoryListItems.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(list.getName());
        if (!isSelectedAll){
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
        else  holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Select all Checkbox in recycler view with data binding**

**In adapter assign globally boolean parameter**

```
public boolean isAllChecked = false;
```

**Create select all method**

```
public void setAllChecked(boolean isAllChecked) {
    this.isAllChecked = isAllChecked;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**In onBind view to write here**

```
if (!isAllChecked) holder.ulbCheckboxBinding.chkBoxUlbName.setChecked(false);
    else holder.ulbCheckboxBinding.chkBoxUlbName.setChecked(true);
```

**Go to your activity and used onclick listener**

```
binding.checkSelectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            adapter.setAllChecked(binding.checkSelectAll.isChecked());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

**thank you**
#android