# Button Checklist all on Recyclerview does not work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have recyclerview with checkbox and I want to checklist all the data using button. I have trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329079/select-all-checkboxes-in-recyclerview?noredirect=1&lq=1) tutorial, but when i click the button, the log is call the isSelectedAll function but can't make the checkbox checked. what wrong with my code?

this is my adapter code

```
var isSelectedAll = false

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListApproveDeatilViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_list_approve_row, parent, false)

    return ListApproveDeatilViewHolder(itemView)
}

private lateinit var mSelectedItemsIds: SparseBooleanArray

fun selectAll() {
    Log.e("onClickSelectAll", "yes")
    isSelectedAll = true
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListApproveDeatilViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val approve = dataSet!![position]

    holder.soal.text = approve.title
    holder.kategori.text = approve.kategori

    if (!isSelectedAll){
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false)
    } else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true)
    }
}
```

and this is my activity code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     private var adapter: ListApproveDetailAdapter? = null

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_approve)
    ButterKnife.bind(this)

    getData()

    // this is my button onclick code

    select.setOnClickListener(){
        if (select.getText().toString().equals("Select all")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + select.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            adapter?.selectAll()
            select.setText("Deselect all")

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + select.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            select.setText("Select all")

        }
    }

}
//this is for get my data for the recyclerview
fun getData() {
    val created_by = intent.getStringExtra(ID_SA)
    val tgl_supervisi = intent.getStringExtra(TGL_SURVEY)
    val no_dlr = intent.getStringExtra(NO_DLR)

    API.getListApproveDetail(created_by, tgl_supervisi, no_dlr).enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<ListApprove>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<ListApprove>>, response: Response<ArrayList<ListApprove>>) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                tempDatas = response.body()
                Log.i("Data Index History", "" + tempDatas)
                recyclerviewApprove?.setHasFixedSize(true)
                recyclerviewApprove?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ListApproveActivity)
                recyclerviewApprove?.adapter = ListApproveDetailAdapter(tempDatas)
                adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@ListApproveActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<ListApprove>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ListApproveActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false

        }
    })

}
```

[image: this is the log when i click the button]

thankyou for any help :)

Comment: I think the problem is you have messes up `adapter` instance . You already created `adapter` inside `onCreate` and you are setting a new adapter inside `getData()`. This is why `notifyDataSetChanged` not worked .

Comment: Replace `recyclerviewApprove?.adapter = ListApproveDetailAdapter(tempDatas)` with `recyclerviewApprove?.adapter = adapter`

Comment: add boolean field to your model class and set its value to true or false and based on that set your checkbox

Comment: @ADM i have replaced `recyclerviewApprove?.adapter = ListApproveDetailAdapter(tempDatas)` with `recyclerviewApprove?.adapter = adapter` but i get null data for recyclerview

Comment: @KaranMer sorry sir, how i set my checkbox? i don't understand

Comment: you set your checkbox as you are now, but add one boolean to `ListApprove` class. change its value true/false as per your condition.

Comment: @KaranMer may i have your email? i want to ask the detail because i'm confused

Comment: you can continue here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184256/discussion-between-ratri-and-karan-mer).

Comment: Why are you not passing _selectAll_ flag to adapter constructor and check by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer with implementation of demo project. I haven't modified your code but as per your requirement i have done this.

**MainActivity class:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var selectAll: Boolean = false;

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView

    val btnSelectAll = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSelectAll) as Button


    //adding a layoutmanager
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)


    //crating an arraylist to store users using the data class user
    val users = ArrayList<User>()

    //adding some dummy data to the list
    users.add(User("Piyush", "Ranchi"))
    users.add(User("Mehul", "Chennai"))
    users.add(User("Karan", "TamilNadu"))
    users.add(User("Bela", "Kolkata"))

    //creating our adapter
    val adapter = CustomAdapter(users, selectAll)

    //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    btnSelectAll.setOnClickListener {

        if (!selectAll) {
            selectAll = true
        } else {
            selectAll = false
        }
        adapter?.selectAllCheckBoxes(selectAll)
    }
    }
    }
```

**User class:**

```
data class User(val name: String, val address: String)
```

**Adapter class:**

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>, val selectAll: Boolean) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

var selectAllA = selectAll;


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.textViewName.text = userList[position].name;

    if (!selectAllA){
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false)
    } else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true)
    }
}

//this method is giving the size of the list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size

}

//the class is hodling the list view
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername) as TextView
    val checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox) as CheckBox
}

 fun selectAllCheckBoxes(selectAll: Boolean) {
     selectAllA = selectAll
     notifyDataSetChanged()
}

}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

As i already mentioned in comments you are using two different adapter instance .
Now i see you have declared `adapter` globally .
Just modify your code as follows and make sure `response.body()` have data int it :

```
 if (response.code() == 200) {
            tempDatas = response.body()
            Log.i("Data Index History", "" + tempDatas)
            recyclerviewApprove?.setHasFixedSize(true)
            recyclerviewApprove?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ListApproveActivity)
            adapter = ListApproveDetailAdapter(tempDatas)
            recyclerviewApprove?.adapter=adapter
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this@ListApproveActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Comment: do I have to delete my private var adapter: ListApproveDetailAdapter? = null declaration?

Comment: NO!! Keep it . Do not use `ListApproveDetailAdapter(tempDatas)` multiple times .

Comment: yes i have changed the code and i can get the data but still can checked when i click the button sir

Answer (score 0):

Add one variable in model class.

like `var isSelect : Boolean`

In your `selectAll()` method update adpter list and notify adapter.

**Edit:**
in the adapter class.

```
if (approve.isSelect){
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true)
    } else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false)
    }
```

Hope this may help you.

**OR**

If you are using **AndroidX** then use should use one `recyclerview` features.

> **androidx.recyclerview.selection**
>
> A RecyclerView addon library providing support for item selection. The
>   library provides support for both touch and mouse driven selection.
>   Developers retain control over the visual representation, and the
>   policies controlling selection behavior (like which items are eligible
>   for selection, and how many items can be selected.)

Reference from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary)

Comment: what must i update in adapter list and notify adapter sir? i dont understand

Comment: update isSelect boolean variable Example: set true in all list item