# how to select all check box by selecting one

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

i have select all contact check box, by selecting this  i want to get all below contact in phone list selected, how can i do that ?/

can anyone please help

i have working below code for single contact select i want to select all 
pleases see the view of app below

[image]
code for single select single check box working

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);
                        ContactObject bean = ContactsListClass.phoneList
                                .get(position);
                        if (bean.isSelected()) {
                            bean.setSelected(false);
                            chk.setChecked(false);

                        } else {
                            bean.setSelected(true);
                            chk.setChecked(true);


                        }

                    }
                });
```

main code

```
  public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment implements CallBack {

Context context = null;
ContactsAdapter objAdapter;
private ArrayList<ContactObject> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactObject>();
private ListView listView;
private ContactsAdapter adapter;
private Button doneBtn , sendBtn;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
TextView buttonAdd;
LinearLayout container;
HorizontalScrollView mHorizontalScrollView;
EditText  textIn;
ContactObject mContactObject;
CallBack mCallBack;
ToggleButton toggleButton;
CheckBox select_all;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    context = getActivity();
    mCallBack = this;
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    listView =(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
//       totalSmsCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TotalMsgSent);
    sendBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
//        totalSmsCount.setText("Total message sent 100/1000");
    mHorizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
    container = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearcontainer);
    textIn = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.textin);
    buttonAdd = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add);
    select_all = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkall);
  //  toggleButton=(ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);


    addContactsInList();

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String msg1 = textIn.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!msg1.equals("") && msg1.length() == 10) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_contact, null);
                TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
                textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString().trim());

                Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                        TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);


                        for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.manualList) {
                            Log.e("remove","bean.getNumber()="+bean.getNumber());
                            Log.e("remove","TextView.getNumber()="+textOut.getText().toString());

                            String str1= bean.getNumber();
                            String str2= textOut.getText().toString();
                            if(str1.equals(str2))
                           {
                               Log.e("remove","Before="+ContactsListClass.manualList.size());
                               Log.e("remove", bean.getNumber());
                               ContactsListClass.manualList.remove(bean);
                               Log.e("remove", "After=" + ContactsListClass.manualList.size());
                               break;
                           }


                        }

                    }
                });

                container.addView(addView);

                mContactObject = new ContactObject();
                mContactObject.setNumber(textIn.getText().toString().trim());
                mContactObject.setName("");
                ContactsListClass.manualList.add(mContactObject);
                textIn.setText("");
                mHorizontalScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mHorizontalScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    }
                }, 100L);

            } else {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Alert")
                        .setMessage("Enter valid number.")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete

                            }
                        })

                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }

        }});
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("Selected contact","size="+ ContactsListClass.phoneList.size());

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.phoneList) {

                    if (bean.isSelected()) {
                        sb.append(bean.getName());
                        sb.append(",");

                        Log.i("Selected contact", sb.toString());
                        contactList.add(bean);


                    }
                }
            for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.manualList) {


                    contactList.add(bean);

            }
            if( contactList.size() > 0  ) {
                container.removeAllViews();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, WriteMessage.class);
//                i.putExtra("Contact_list",  contactList);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }else{

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("No Contact")
                        .setMessage("Please select atleast one contact.")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    contactList.clear();
    if(objAdapter!= null) {
        objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.manualList) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_contact, null);
        TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
        textOut.setText(bean.getNumber());

        Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                TextView textOut = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);


                for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.manualList) {
                    Log.e("remove", "bean.getNumber()=" + bean.getNumber());
                    Log.e("remove", "TextView.getNumber()=" + textOut.getText().toString());

                    String str1 = bean.getNumber();
                    String str2 = textOut.getText().toString();
                    if (str1.equals(str2)) {
                        Log.e("remove", "Before=" + ContactsListClass.manualList.size());
                        Log.e("remove", bean.getNumber());
                        ContactsListClass.manualList.remove(bean);
                        Log.e("remove", "After=" + ContactsListClass.manualList.size());
                        break;
                    }


                }

            }
        });

        container.addView(addView);




    }
    mHorizontalScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mHorizontalScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    }, 100L);
}



private void getSelectedContacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.phoneList) {

        if (bean.isSelected()) {
            sb.append(bean.getName());
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }

    String s = sb.toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Select atleast one Contact",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts : " + s,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

private void addContactsInList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            showPB();

            try {
//                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},1);
                Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, null, null, null);

                try {
                    ContactsListClass.phoneList.clear();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneName = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));

                    String phoneImage = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI));


                    ContactObject cp = new ContactObject();



                    cp.setName(phoneName);
                    cp.setNumber(phoneNumber);
                    cp.setImage(phoneImage);

                    ContactsListClass.phoneList.add(cp);

                }
                phones.close();



                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //                            llContainer.addView(lv);
                        objAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(),
                                ContactsListClass.phoneList,mCallBack);
                        listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
                        objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                });

                Collections.sort(ContactsListClass.phoneList,
                        new Comparator<ContactObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(ContactObject lhs,
                                               ContactObject rhs) {
                                return lhs.getName().compareTo(
                                        rhs.getName());
                            }
                        });



                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);
                        ContactObject bean = ContactsListClass.phoneList
                                .get(position);
                        if (bean.isSelected()) {
                            bean.setSelected(false);
                            chk.setChecked(false);

                        } else {
                            bean.setSelected(true);
                            chk.setChecked(true);


                        }

                    }
                });


            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            hidePB();

        }
    };
    thread.start();

}

void showPB() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

void hidePB() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
public void onEventCheck(ContactObject mContactObject)
{
    setContact(mContactObject);
}
void setContact(ContactObject mContactObject)
{
    Log.e("remove","inside setContact");
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_contact, null);
    TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
    textOut.setText(mContactObject.getNumber());

    Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
    buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
            TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);


            for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.manualList) {
                Log.e("remove","bean.getNumber()="+bean.getNumber());
                Log.e("remove","TextView.getNumber()="+textOut.getText().toString());

                String str1= bean.getNumber();
                String str2= textOut.getText().toString();
                if(str1.equals(str2))
                {
                    Log.e("remove","Before="+ContactsListClass.manualList.size());
                    Log.e("remove", bean.getNumber());
                    ContactsListClass.manualList.remove(bean);
                    Log.e("remove", "After=" + ContactsListClass.manualList.size());
                    break;
                }


            }

        }
    });

    container.addView(addView);
    mHorizontalScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mHorizontalScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    }, 100L);

}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690605/selecting-all-items-in-a-listview-on-checkbox-select

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `ArrayList<CheckBox> array_checkBox` and always that a `CheckBox`is created, you need to add this `CheckBox`in the `array_checkBox`.

For Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CheckBox main_Checkbox;
private CheckBox checkBox1;
private CheckBox checkBox2;
private CheckBox checkBox3;
private ArrayList<CheckBox> array_checkBox = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    main_Checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.mainCheckBox);
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

    //Add a checkBox in the array (do it for each new CheckBox)
    array_checkBox.add(checkBox1);
    array_checkBox.add(checkBox2);
    array_checkBox.add(checkBox3);

    main_Checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //if the Main CheckBox is checked, check all CheckBoxs
            if (isChecked){

                for (int j = 0; j < array_checkBox.size(); j++){
                    array_checkBox.get(j).setChecked(true);
                }
                //Else, uncheck all CheckBoxs
            }else{

                for (int j = 0; j < array_checkBox.size(); j++){
                    array_checkBox.get(j).setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```