# Remove all my item in Listview

Tags: java, android

I have a `Listview` in my row, I have check box to select a item to delete.
I want to have a button to select all my items and delete them at same time.
When I click my button to select all the items, only the last item gets selected.

Here is my code:

```
 all.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for(int i=0;i<listview.getChildCount();i++){
                    Log.i("mhs",listview.getChildCount()+"");
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                }


            }
        });
```

Here is my `Adaptor` :

```
  public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // This would hold the database objects i.e. Blacklist
    private List<Blacklist> records;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.records = objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Reuse the view to make the scroll effect smooth
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        // Fetch phone number from the database object
        final Blacklist phoneNumber = records.get(position);

        // Set to screen component to display results
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial_tv)).setText("" + (position + 1));
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number_tv)).setText(phoneNumber.phoneNumber);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
        final LinearLayout me = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.me);
        if (position + 1 >= 1) {
            me.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {



                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                    // Set the appropriate message into it.
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.block));

                    // Add a positive button and it's action. In our case action would be deletion of the data
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    try {

                                        blackListDao.delete(blockList.get(position));

                                        // Removing the same from the List to remove from display as well
                                        blockList.remove(position);
                                        listview.invalidateViews();

                                        // Reset the value of selectedRecordPosition
                                        selectedRecordPosition = -1;
                                        populateNoRecordMsg();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                    // Add a negative button and it's action. In our case, just hide the dialog box
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                                }
                            });

                    // Now, create the Dialog and show it.
                    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            }
        });
        all.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for(int i=0;i<listview.getChildCount();i++){
                    Log.i("mhs",listview.getChildCount()+"");
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    listview.removeView(i);
                }


            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

How to select all the items together?

Comment: Just clear your list like YOUR_ARRAYLIST.clear(); And make sure to use the notifiyDatachange after clear the list

Comment: post your adapter class also

Comment: I assume you want to delete item from some kind of persistance system DB, file ... You have just to delete all this item and then update your adapter

Comment: my last item just selected.now i don not clear anything. first i must get them to gether after that delet them

Comment: Mate what is 'checkbox'? You are doing a for loop, but aren't using the increment to get the current item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting All Items in a Listview on checkbox select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690605/selecting-all-items-in-a-listview-on-checkbox-select)

Comment: @VivekMishra i post it

Answer (score 0):

The issue with a listview is that the views are recycled! That means that calling

```
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

Will simply just edit the current active item. If you want to remove all the items the best way to do so is to clear the list you are using, and the notifyingDataSetChanged().

Comment: how to clear my list?how to tik all my check box and then delete them?

Comment: you mean mylistview.clear? I can not understand you mean

Comment: A better approach might be to use listView.setAdapter(null);

Comment: yes but I want to select first my item then delete them

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop add this:

```
currentCheckBox = listView.getChildAt(i);
//now you should have the correct checkBox
```

Edit: if your needs is simply deleting the data and clearing, I'd make a method just for that. Call it, delete the items from db, then .clear() the adapter. (can't remember if notifyDatasetChanged() is called autmatically here, do it if not)